# SQL not returning expected rows

Tags: mysql, sql

My SQL SELECT statement is not returning the correct rows. I have a table named activities and the statement should only output the rows where the column 'approved' = yes and where some of the cells have some text LIKE 'test'. But my statement is still outputting some of the rows where approved = no, however not all of them.

This is my sql statement:

```
SELECT * FROM activities WHERE approved = 'yes' AND title LIKE '%test%' OR subject LIKE '%test%' OR industry LIKE '%test%' OR description LIKE '%test%' ORDER BY date_added DESC
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operator-precedence.html

Answer (score 2):

Move all the OR conditions within `()` something as

```
SELECT * FROM activities
WHERE 
approved = 'yes' 
AND ( 
title LIKE '%test%' 
OR subject LIKE '%test%'
OR industry LIKE '%test%' 
OR description LIKE '%test%' 
)
ORDER BY date_added DESC
```

So it will do the filter as

- if approved = 'yes'
- AND title like something or subject like something ....